# Icon in kendoUI grid column in MVC application (using MVC wrappers)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

I have a page in ASP.NET MVC app, made with KendoUI
The page has a hierarchical grid (as at the link below)

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/hierarchy.html

Code works fine.

The details grid is bound to following class

```
public class ScheduledInspectionInfo
{
    public ScheduledInspectionInfo();

    public string CommandName { get; set; }
    public string IconPath { get; set; }
    public int InspectionID { get; set; }
    public DateTime PeriodEndDate { get; set; }
    public int PeriodNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime PeriodStartDate { get; set; }
    public int PermitID { get; set; }
}
```

The IconName field contains name of an icon I need to show in grid.
But I cannot make it work

If I define the grid as below:

```
Html.Kendo().Grid<MyPermitNow.ScheduledInspectionInfo>()
    .Name("grid_#=PermitID#")   
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.PeriodNo).Title("No.").Width(200);
        columns.Bound(p => p.PeriodStartDate).Format("{0:d}").Width(200);
        columns.Bound(p => p.PeriodEndDate).Format("{0:d}").Width(200);
        columns.Bound(p => p.IconPath).Title("Status");
    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(5)        
        .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_SearchDetail", "Septic", new { permitID = "#=PermitID#" }))
    )
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .ToClientTemplate()
```

the Status column shows the icon name

But if I change Status column definition as below

```
columns.Bound(p => p.IconPath).Title("Status").ClientTemplate("<img src='#= IconName #' />");
```

It gives me JavaScript error:

```
ReferenceError: IconName is not defined
```

when trying to expand master row to see details

Any idea what can be wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `IconPath` is defined is the detail object, for your template you have to escape `#` character in order to access to the detail (`#= ... #` maps to properties of the master element and `\\#= ... \\#` to a detail element).

In your case, you should then use :

```
columns.Bound(p => p.IconPath)
       .Title("Status")
       .ClientTemplate("<img src='\\#= IconPath \\#' />");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you misspelled something. The IconName Attribute is never defined.

Try the IconPath instead

```
columns.Bound(p => p.IconPath).Title("Status").ClientTemplate("<img src='#= IconPath #' />");
```

Comment: Thanks, I missspelled, but in the post.